# Does Amazon Redshift have variable/path/table dropdowns when querying?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In BigQuery when you type something and wait a moment, there is a dropdown that lists directories that match or partially match what you've typed so far, or variable names from a table already declared in the FROM statement.

Is there a way to toggle this in Redshift? It's super useful when I don't want to have to scroll all the way across a large table to find how a particular variable is exactly named/spelled.

**DESIRED RESULT**

For example if I have the following statement:

```
SELECT id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       p

FROM users
```

Assuming I just typed the 'p' in the last line of the SELECT statement, I'd like a dropdown to pop up showing variable names within the table `users` that start with 'p' (eg. 'phone_number', 'pronouns'). Is this something Redshift has?

Right now when I type some characters, there are things that pop up as suggestions but they are only other tables/directories that match or partially match. I'm wondering if there's a way to have this extend to variable names within a table that's already been declared in the FROM statement, similar to how BigQuery does it.

Comment: I presume you are referring to the Query Editor in the Redshift management console? Or are you using your own SQL client (which one)?

Comment: I agree - this is a function of the client, not the database. What client are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Query Editor in Redshift